# Delete some files in folder

Tags: php

I have a cronjob that removes every day all unused files, but I will wish to go further. My files are this structure `name_number.jpg`, but some files have this structure `name_.jpg`.

Currently my script does not make a difference and removes all. I wish the script to remove the `name_number.jpg` without erasing the files without number.

```
$days = 1;  
$path = './result/';  

// Open the directory  
if ($handle = opendir($path))  
{  
    // Loop through the directory  
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))  
    {  
        // Check the file we're doing is actually a file  
        if (is_file($path.$file))  
        {  
            // Check if the file is older than X days old  
            if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) )  
            {  
                // Do the deletion  
                unlink($path.$file);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: change `if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) )` to `if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) && preg_match('@_\d+\.[a-zA-Z]{3}$@', $file) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Iterators:

```
$days = 1;

$fsi = new RegexIterator(
    new FilesystemIterator('/path/to/your/files'),
    '(.+_\d+\.jpg$)'
);
/** @var SplFileObject $file */
foreach ($fsi as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile() && $file->getMTime() < strtotime("-$days day")) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Functional approach:

```
$days = 1;

array_map(
    function($file) use ($days) {
        if (!is_dir($file) && filemtime($file) < strtotime("-$days day")) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    },
    glob('/path/to/your/files/*_[1-9].jpg')
);
```

Good old imperative:

```
$days = 1;

foreach (glob('/path/to/your/files/*_[1-9].jpg') as $file) {
    if (!is_dir($file) && filemtime($file) < strtotime("-$days day")) {
        unlink($file);
    }
};
```